# Python: overloading the __getattr__ and properties, making __setattr__ work correctly

Tags: python, properties

Consider the following python code:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return "value: {v}".format(v=self._value)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo('foo')

    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Intercepts attribute calls, and if we don't have it, look at the
        webelement to see if it has the attribute.
        """

        # Check first to see if it looks like a method, if not then just return
        # the attribute the way it is.
        # Note: this has only been tested with variables, and methods.
        if not hasattr(getattr(self.foo, attr), '__call__'):
            return getattr(self.foo, attr)

        def callable(*args, **kwargs):
            '''
            Returns the method from the webelement module if found
            '''
            return getattr(self.foo, attr)(*args, **kwargs)
        return callable

>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.foo
<__main__.Foo object at 0x819410>
>>> b.foo.value
'value: foo'
>>> b.foo.value = '2'
>>> b.foo.value
'value: 2'
>>> b.value
'value: 2'
>>> b.value = '3'
>>> b.value
'3'
```

That last part, I want it to be 'value: 3' instead of '3' because now my property 'value' is now an attribute instead.

Is it possible, and if it is how would I would I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `__getattr__` returns the property *value*, not the property itself. When you access `getattr(self.foo, attr)` it does the equivalent of `self.foo.value` and returns that, and the property is called at that time.

You thus need to implement a `__setattr__` method too, to mirror the `__getattr__` and pass on the value setting to the contained `foo` object.

Under the hood, Python implements properties as [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors); their [`__get__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) is called by the lower-level [`__getattribute__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes), which causes them to return their computed value. It is never the property object itself that is returned.

Here's an example `__setattr__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if hasattr(self, 'foo') and hasattr(self.foo, attr):
        setattr(self.foo, attr, value)
        return
    super(Bar, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
```

Note: because your `__init__` sets `self.foo`, you need to test if `foo` exists on your class (`hasattr(self, 'foo')`. You also need to call the original `__setattr__` implementation to make sure that things like `self.foo = Foo()` work still.

Comment: So how do I implement such a __setattr__. i tried but not sure how to do it properly. Thanks Martijn!

Comment: @glouie: added an example `__setattr__` for you.